# displaying a list of categories in ASC order, but "OTHERS" in last

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying a list of categories in ASC order."OTHERS" is also one of the category. I need to display all categories in ASC ORDER and "OTHERS" in last .

This is done by using PHP and MYSQL.

TABLE STRUCTURE

tale name: categories

```
id categoryname

1  APPLE

2  BANANA

3  Strawberry

4  Other

5  grape
```

For example: the above is the table structure. From the above table i need to display all the categories in ASC Order and need to display "OTHER" at last. **So the output should be
exactly like below.**

```
id categoryname

1  APPLE

2  BANANA

3  grape

4  Strawberry 

5  Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Categories
ORDER BY    CASE 
                WHEN Categorie = 'OTHERS' THEN 2 
                ELSE 1 
            END, 
            Categorie
```

Comment: I believe this will only sort 'others' to the end of the list, and not sort the categories.

Comment: The order by clause has 2 sections, so try running it and see. It will sort asc by the 1/2 id and then by Category.

Comment: will you please explain me the query astander.. I am new to CASE in mysql.. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Sorry, I misread the query, and didn't see the second part of the clause. Light blue on grey at the end of a long day I guess. Perhaps I just stopped reading when I saw the word `END` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY categories LIKE 'others' ASC, categories ASC
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer, except in de question 'Other' is used. it's more simple and clear than the use of a CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 ASC, Column3 DESC
```

Comment: please view the question again seyfo. I explained it in breif

Comment: No need sorry Seyfo... Just FYI.